# How did the Terminator survive teleporting?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

In the *Terminator* movie, during the teleportation scene, how is it that he survived? Since he is a machine, wouldn't the lightning/static fry and damage any internal components? Normally with any machine it gets damaged with a lightning strike, I figured it would be the same in this instance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be called *time-traveling* instead of teleporting?

Comment: The fact that you use the word 'normally' in a scenario involving a time-traveling cyborg may be significant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even in the real world, electrical discharges don't always harm well-designed equipment. For example, a [Faraday cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) is a shielding mechanism that protects internal components from electrical damage by conducting charges around the outside the cage. There are special alloys like [Mu metal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal) that provide good shielding. It's not much of a leap that this technology would be adopted and improved in the Terminators.

Answer (score 4):

> A deleted scene from Terminator 2 shows John Connor and several Resistance fighters, including Kyle Reese, taking over the building where the TDE is housed in 2029.

I can't find an exact source, but I remember hearing the method of Time Travel utilised by Sky Net and the Resistance destroys all exposed inorganic substances. I also heard something about a Bio-Field needed by the time travel device. Both the reason the T-800 (coated in living flesh, and thus safe) and Kyle get round this is by arriving naked (or are stripped of anything inorganic in the process).

How this is countered by the T-1000 and T-X I don't know.

Here's a [quote](http://www.hopeofthefuture.net/deletedscenes/t2omit04.html) form the script of the deleted scene, it doesn't state explicitly anywhere about it needing flesh, but this is as close as I can get:

> As he finishes stripping off his battle
>   uniform, the techs begin smearing his body with a
>   conductive so the time-field will follow his outline.

Supposedly that coating is then stripped off, perhaps this would damage an un-fleshed Terminator?

Comment: Metallic stuff seems to react poorly. Inorganic material simply disappears.